# gateaux derivative and frechet derivative

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

In calculus, we have the following equation $DF(x,y)=\partial F_xdx+\partial F_ydy$ if $F$ is differentiable. I think such equation still holds for frechet derivative, but not for gateaux derivative.

So do we have a similar version of this equation when we are using gateaux derivative to find the derivative of a function like $F(x,y)$?

Thanks!

Comment: The gateaux derivative need not to be linear.

Comment: So such equation will only hold if we impose some linear condition?

Comment: And is there some general equation for gateaux derivative $Df(x,y)$ given that it may not linear?

Comment: Okay. Some demand linearity, some not. In case the Gateaux is linear, you can represent it as a matrix multiplication. **However: The chain rule does not work for Gateaux derivative in general. So you may not interpret $dx$ as derivative of an other function $x$!** (cf. an old question [Multivariable Chain Rule for partially differentiable maps](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361386/multivariable-chain-rule-for-partially-differentiable-maps/1361411#1361411).

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "represent it as a matrix multiplication"? Is there some example for this sentence?

Comment: A linear mapping from $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ is identical to the left multiplication with a suitable $1\times 2$ matrix.

Comment: So what will the matrix be like in case of $Df(x,y)$? Does a general form exist if we assume gateaux derivative to be linear?(or extra condition for such existence is needed?)

Comment: $[\partial F_x, \partial F_y]$ just like the Jacobian. Notice that I meant linearity in $(dx, dy)$, not linearity in $(x,y)$.

Comment: So in this case, does it coincide with frechet derivative?

Comment: it is the same mapping, but the existance of the mapping does not implies that it has the property of a frechet derivative, namely the linear approximation property: $F(x+h, y+k) - F(x,y) - \partial F_x h - \partial F_y k = o(\|(h,k)\|)$.

Comment: So if we do not assume linearity in $dx,dy$, what can we say about $Df(x,y)$?

Comment: it is homogen in $(dx, dy)$. cf. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gâteaux_derivative

Comment: @user251257   If f and g are gateaux differentiable, will gateaux derivative be the same as frechet derivative?

Comment: gateaux derivative  of $f\circ g$ I mean

Comment: No, cf my answer at [Multivariable Chain Rule for partially differentiable maps](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361386/multivariable-chain-rule-for-partially-differentiable-maps/1361411#1361411).